# can't get data outside onResponse Retrofit

Tags: android, variables, asynchronous, retrofit

I can't get the data outside onResponse in Restrofit

this is my code

```
List<Categorie> categorylist=new ArrayList<>();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    final CategoryApi api = retrofit.create(CategoryApi.class);



    Call<List<Categorie>> categoryCall = api.categories();


        categoryCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Categorie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Categorie>> call, Response<List<Categorie>> response) {
                categorylist = (List<Categorie>)response.body();
                Log.i("success","Inside "+categorylist.toString());

                // here i get the data

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Categorie>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Erreur");
            }
        });

        Log.i("success","Outside "+categorylist.toString());

        // here i get null
```

i've tried making categorylist volatile and static and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to access `categorylist` immediately after calling `categoryCall.enqueue`.  `enqueue` is an asynchronous operation which will not complete before the next line ( containing `categorylist.toString()`) is executed.

Try calling another method where you've left the comment "here i get the data"

`public void onResponse(/*...*/ response) {
        categorylist = (List<Categorie>)response.body();
        Log.i("success","Inside "+categorylist.toString());
        // here i get the data
        businessLogic(categorieslist);
    }
    private void businessLogc(List<Categorie> categories) {
        myView.showCategories(categories); // or whatever you're doing with data
}`

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that and it's working . I have a lot of methods and I need the cetegorylist variable outside the callback so I can handle it freely .

Answer (score 0):

You know, http request is a process that require time, so it should be done asynchronously. Fortunately retrofit handle everything for us.

What you need to do, is when we get response from OnResponse, you need to update your current view, for example if you're using recyclerview, there is recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

If you want to get the result from beginning. I'm suggest you call the enqueue method in other activity or somewhere else, and then when you get the result, save it into sqlite database.

And then when you open CategoryActivity load it from database.

You can add refresh button to call the enqueue again to update the database.